# How to check for data in a child, in a child in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The title maybe looks wrong, but its what I am trying to figure out how to do this. My data structure looks like this:

[image: data structure]

I want to look if there are users presented in every channel. This will work to check if there are channels:

```
channelRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
for channelSnap in snapshot.children {
let channelData = (channelSnap as! FIRDataSnapshot).value as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
if let name = channelData["name"] as! String!, name.characters.count > 0 {
}
})
```

This will of course check if there is a child with a property called name, and if so, do stuff. What I want to do, is the loop through the children (users in a channel) in the children(a channels) in all channels. I want to check if the channel has any children's in it, if not, remove that channel. So how to loop through the children in the channel children? I have access to every channels ID by calling this function:

let id = (channelSnap as! FIRDataSnapshot).key

Edit:

This prints out No user in channel:

```
channelRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
            for channelSnap in snapshot.children {
                for child in (channelSnap as AnyObject).children {
                    let usersData = (child as! FIRDataSnapshot).value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                    if let randomUser = usersData?["userID"] as! String!{
                        print("user in the channel")
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        print("no user in channel")
                    }
                }
```

Edit 2:

This is a print of snapshot, followed by a print of channelSnap, **while there is a user in it**:

```
SNAPSHOT: Snap (channels) {
    "-KePh6YFmQqQ6ZhEfTHn" =     {
        "-KePh6YHPLSAIEARfj-i" =         {
            PictureVersion = 2;
            readyToGo = 0;
            userID = SZlQ76RLCJQpFa0CDhrgFJoYzrs2;
            username = pietje;
        };
        creator = SZlQ76RLCJQpFa0CDhrgFJoYzrs2;
        currentPlayers = 1;
        entryFee = 100;
        gameType = normal;
        maximumPlayers = 4;
        name = "random channel";
        password = "";
    };
}
CHANNELSNAP: Snap (-KePh6YFmQqQ6ZhEfTHn) {
    "-KePh6YHPLSAIEARfj-i" =     {
        PictureVersion = 2;
        readyToGo = 0;
        userID = SZlQ76RLCJQpFa0CDhrgFJoYzrs2;
        username = pietje;
    };
    creator = SZlQ76RLCJQpFa0CDhrgFJoYzrs2;
    currentPlayers = 1;
    entryFee = 100;
    gameType = normal;
    maximumPlayers = 4;
    name = "random channel";
    password = "";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: users in channel?]

Is the `KeJTqVREbMEmtD0oAk4` a user inside the channel? If so I think it would be nice to have a key `users` where you would keep all the informations about them...

In the image below, The `example` key would correspond to your channel. Inside it, you'd have `other_info`, which would be the informations about that channel. Then, there's `users`, which will keep all the different users that are in the channel.

[image]

Then `channelSnap.child("users").value` would have all the users in that channel.

You could check whether there are users with something like:

```
if let dict = channelSnap.child("users").value as? [String: Any] {
   if dict.count == 0 {
      // no users
   } else {
      // you got users
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, KeJTqVREbMEmtD0oAk4  is a random user. This could work, but I would like to do it my way else I get more and more maps. Is it possible to search in a channel for a key called "userID", since every user in that channels is supposed to have one? If there are no key's for userID, there are no users. I would like to hear if this is possible!

Comment: Yeah.. you can, but the problem is the `userId` is inside a radom id, so you'd have to go search for it everywhere.. unless you have a reference to that key somewhere..

Comment: But if you want to do it, you'd have to add another `for` in the channelSnap.children.. 
```for channelSnap in shapshot.children {
      for child in channelSnap.children {
         // look for the userId here
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I forgot to include I have access to every channels unique id. It is: let id = (channelSnap as! FIRDataSnapshot).key Is it now possible to check for children in every channels?

Comment: I updated my question. I was trying to loop again through the children, but it gives me a print no user, while there is a user in that channel.

Comment: Well.. it is possible. You can get the channelSnap.children.. if you had the keys for the users-channel relationship (which in your picture is the `KeJTqVREbMEmtD0oAk4`) then you could look for those.. but anyway, you can look for all the children and try to get the `userId` inside each of them. If you have it somewhere, there's a user.. However, I still think having a `users` key would make it a lot easier =D

Comment: could you put a break point in the inner loop and print out to the console what the `channelSnap` looks like?

Comment: Yes I now included 2 prints, thank you again for all of your help. I hope we can sort this out :(

Comment: Are you using swift 3? If you are, try replacing `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>` with `Dictionary<String, Any>`. I don't know if thats the reason, but there's a `Bool` inside the snapshot and it doesn't conform to AnyObject..

Answer (score 1):

If you create a key for players will be easy check if have the player and retrieve the data. 
[image: Will look like this:]

To catch the data will be like this:

```
ref.child("channels").observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let data = snapshot.value as! [String:AnyObject]? else { return print("Snapshot error!")}
        if let player = data["players"] {
            for player in player as! [String:[String:AnyObject]] {
                print(player.key)
                print(player.value as Any)
            }
        } else {
            print("No player found!")
        }
    })
```