# Swift/Firebase : Access and store data to array

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to access all the questions in the tree that starts from

`var ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("trivia")`

and when I print the contents with the following function

```
func observeQuestion(completion: @escaping (Trivia) -> Void) {
    ref.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        if let dict = snapshot.value {
            print("\(dict)")
        }
    })
}
```

I get the tree as follows

[image]

But I can't figure out how to access the `Question` and print that out, it always comes out as `nil`. I want to access all the questions value and store them in an array. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
let questions = snapshot.value as! [[String: Any]]
for question in questions {
    let title = question["Question"]!
    print("Question: \(title)")
}
```

Comment: I think that approach would work. Maybe OP could look at this answers swell: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42599617/how-to-check-for-data-in-a-child-in-a-child-in-firebase

Comment: Thanks @J.Doe! Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40055996/819340) might also be helpful.

Comment: Yes! Thank you Mr. Mattos!!